# How to simulate pressing Enter?

Tags: linux, bash

I have this in my bash script:

```
ENV_VAR1=123 nohup my_app &
```

When I run, it prints this

```
$ nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
# <here is a new line>
```

and expects me to press Enter so that it'll present me again the promt for continuing entering commands. After I press Enter, I endeed get this:

```
$
```

How can I simulate pressing Enter **in my bash script**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic way to simulate Enter in a bash script.

You are not expected to press enter so that you get again the prompt for continuing entering commands. The prompt for entering commands is already there, it's the `$` in front of `nohup`. It's just that the message from `nohup` follows this prompt. You can avoid this message by redirecting to output yourself.

```
ENV_VAR1=123 nohup my_app >> nohup.out 2>&1 &
```